# Arduino LED Dimmer Proportionate to Ambient Light

Tags: led, pwm

I am trying to get an LED dimming reversely proportionate to natural light level in a room.
So as the sun rises, the LED dims and vice-versa.
I am using the standard LDR+ 10k Ohm resistor divider, an LED, and an Arduino Leonardo Clone.

The issue is, regardless of the values I adjust in `map()`, it does not change the flickering rate or brightness of the LED.
What range of map shuold I be using?

The LED ought to shut off while the LDR takes a reading. 
I have two variations of the code; one uses PWM, the other simulates PWM using `delay()`

Here are my sketches:

```
/set pin numbers
//const won't change
const int ledPin = 1;   //D1 the number of the LED pin (OR to MOSFET input wire for controlling high power LED
const int ldrPin = A0;  // A0 the number of the LDR pin
//10K ohm resistor as voltage reference.


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  //initialize the LED pin as an output
  pinMode(ldrPin, INPUT);   //initialize the LDR pin as an input
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); //Shutoff LED invisibly rapid to get a reading of the ambient light without the LED on
  int ldrStatus = analogRead(ldrPin);   //read the status of the light sensor value
  // KEEP LED OFF TIME BASED ON AMBIENT LIGHT LEVEL...
  int dim2 = map(ldrStatus, 0, 1023, 500, 0); //OFF FOR UP TO 0.50 seconds.
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(dim2);

   }
```

Sketch two:

```
//set pin numbers
//const won't change
const int ledPin = 1;   //D1 the number of the LED pin (OR to MOSFET input wire for controlling high power LED
const int ldrPin = A0;  // A0 the number of the LDR pin
//10K OHM resistor as voltage reference.

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  //initialize the LED pin as an output
  pinMode(ldrPin, INPUT);   //initialize the LDR pin as an input
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); //Shutoff LED invisibly rapid to get a reading of the ambient light without the LED on
  int ldrStatus = analogRead(ldrPin);   //read the status of the light sensor value
  int dim = map(ldrStatus, 0, 1023, 255, 0);     // scale it to use it with the LED (value between 0 and 255)
  digitalWrite(ledPin, dim);               //Flash LED at that rate to adjust brightness.

   }
```

Comment: Why do you think you should be using `digitalWrite()`?

Comment: I was mistaken. I switched it to `analogWrite()` , but no changes happened.

Comment: You need to use PWM pin, like pin 3, but  different sets for different Arduinos.

Answer (score 1):

For certain Arduino models, the PWM pins are different. For the iteaduino lite, a usable PWM pin is pin D5.

Here is the code updated to use D5 instead of D1, which lacks PWM abilities:

```
//set pin numbers
//const won't change
const int ledPin = 5;   //D5 PWM the number of the LED pin (OR to MOSFET input wire for controlling high power LED
const int ldrPin = A0;  // A0 the number of the LDR pin
//10K OHM resistor as voltage reference.

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  //initialize the LED pin as an output
  pinMode(ldrPin, INPUT);   //initialize the LDR pin as an input
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); //Shutoff LED invisibly rapid to get a reading of the ambient light without the LED on
  int ldrStatus = analogRead(ldrPin);   //read the status of the light sensor value
  int dim = map(ldrStatus, 0, 1023, 0, 255);     // scale it to use it with the LED (value between 0 and 255)
  analogWrite(ledPin, dim);               //Flash LED at that rate to adjust brightness.
  Serial.println(dim);
   }
```

There is still flickering, but that is to be expected. `map()` ranges can be adjusted to set when the LED will be fully off or on.

It is still unclear how to allow the light sensor to take a reading while the LED is OFF, then power back on rapidly enough to not have a visible flicker. 
If anyone has thoughts on that, it would be appreciated!
Thanks everyone for helping.

Comment: `analogRead()` is slow. You should consider using the ADC at a lower level if you need improved speed.